# How to load environment variables with Unicorn

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I can't seem to get my server to load up the environment variables. In my ideal setup I would like 1 user (deployer) to serve multiple applications on a single server. Ubuntu 12.04, Nginx, Unicorn.

In my apps I have a .env file that contain all the environment variables the app needs.

Here are my failed attempts:

I start unicorn with the special shell script. I can't use source here so I don't have any idea how to load the environment variables in it.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=<%= current_path %>
PID=<%= unicorn_pid %>
CMD="cd <%= current_path %>; bundle exec unicorn -D -c <%= unicorn_config %> -E <%= rails_env %>"
AS_USER=<%= user %>
set -u

# source doesn't work ...
source <%= current_path %>/.env

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

I also tried setting the ENV values manually in the unicorn.rb configuration script. But somehow this doesn't even work!

```
before_exec do |server|
  ENV["START_BEFORE_EXEC"] = "Hello"
end

puts "UNICORN ENV DEBUG:"
ENV.each{ |k, v| puts "#{k}:tt#{v}" }
```

In the unicorn.log file I can see the environment variables but sadly not the START_BEFORE_EXEC one ... how is this possible?

EDIT: Working but not how I imagine it should work:

I finally got it working by placing some ruby code after the configuration block in application.rb. It read in the file and places it manually in ENV. There has to be a better way but for now it works. Is there a better way? I'll test it and accept an answer if ok.

Comment: Does changing your CMD line to `START_BEFORE_EXEC=Hello bundle exec unicorn ...` work?

Comment: Did this. Not displayed on the "UNICORN ENV DEBUG" output. Good idea though. Edited my question because I sort of figured out a way. But it's far from perfect.

Comment: you might want to ask this over at StackOverflow, where there are more Ruby developers who may have run into this, than Sysadmins who are less familiar.

Comment: But I think the environment variables should be passable / settable from the OS, no? What's the correct way to set the ENV variables in a Nginx / Unicorn setup?

Comment: We've tended to run the unicorn bit through bluepill (so it can kick unicorn if it exceeds memory, bring it back up if it falls down, etc.  The env variables are set through bluepill configuration.  The nginx configuration isn't involved with this at all, as nginx just functions as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Ok I'll definitely try bluepill.

Comment: There's also `god`.  Bluepill generally works, though once in a while we want to punch it.  But not so much that we want to go through the hassle of switching to something else.

Comment: Was also checking out god & monit to see what's best :p But thx :D